# Django: Outlook email smtp timeout in production server

Tags: python, django, email, outlook, smtp

i'm trying to send a SMTP email from Django, using my credentials of Outlook. My code works in localhost, but when I upload my code to production server, it doesn't.

If I use my Gmail credential, it also works in production, but it doesn't with Outlook. So, I think Outlook is configured in a different way, but I dont know.

This is my view code:

```
def send_my_custom_email():

    connection = mail.get_connection(
        host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
        port = 25,
        username = 'myemail@outlook.com',
        password = 'mypassword' ,
        )
    connection.open()

    email2send  = mail.EmailMessage('hello', 'hello', 'myemail@outlook.com', to=['receiveremail'], connection=connection)

    email2send.send()
    connection.close()
```

I know that my configuration setting are right because it can send emails from localhost. These are my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I already try to check the Outlook settings, but I couldn't find anything about SMTP use.

My exact questions are:

1. Outlook need aditional settings in production?
2. The problem is in my code or in Outlook settings?
3. Why it works in localhost but it does not in production server?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook.com only allows encrypted SMTP TLS connections on port 587. It does not even listen on port 25, that is why you get a timeout.

Comment: the port 25 works for me in the localhost. I tried your suggestion and it still timeout on port 587. There is another setting for the encrypted SMTP TLS?

Comment: It works locally because your local host listens on port 25. Outlook.com does not. Did you specify TLS when using port 587?

Comment: I am pointing outlook server from my localhost, I am not using a local SMTP server. the only way I know to specigy TLS is putting "EMAIL_USE_TLS = True" in my settings.py, I dont know if it has to be configured in the connection settings

Comment: It turns out to be a server problem, I'am Using Gooogle cloud Compute Engine and this plataform blocks the ports "587", "25" and "465" (and only allow them for using Gmail).